# How to Create threads recursively without Loops

Tags: pthreads

I would like to create a code that will:
create recursive threads without using loops, the threads has to execute certain routine. I am using Pthread_create on ubuntu

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 8

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
  printf("\n%d: Hello World!\n", threadid);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  int rc, t;
  for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++)
  {
    printf("Creating thread %d\n", t);
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
    if (rc)
    {
      printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your specific problem? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to ask good questions.

Comment: sorry if that was a confusion, my below code should create 8 threads and print Hello World with the thread ID, I wanted to do same with recurssion withou using for loop

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to C programming and to the forum. thanks for your understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create thread without using `for` loop , I have modified your code and used function recursion to create pthread..

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 8
pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
    printf("\n%d: Hello World!\n", threadid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void create_thread(int n){

    if (n > 0 ){  
        //Create thread 
        printf("Creating thread %d\n", ((NUM_THREADS - n) + 1) );
        //NUM_THREADS - n to start index from 0 
        int rc = pthread_create(&threads[NUM_THREADS - n], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)(NUM_THREADS - n));
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
        n--;
        create_thread(n);
    }   
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int rc, t;

    create_thread( NUM_THREADS );

    //Wait to finish all thread
    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[t],NULL);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;

}
```

Hope this will help you.